# Can't send e-mail

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gmail

I'm trying to implement a mailing function using the SMTP from Gmail. The following code snippets work fine using either emailjs (npm) or gmail-send (npm).

Locally it works perfect, but when I deploy it on my Ubuntu VPS it won't work. I keep getting timeouts to the SMTP.

emailjs:

```
var email   = require("emailjs");
var server  = email.server.connect({
    user:    "from-email@gmail.com",
    password:"password",
    host:    "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:  465,
    ssl:     true
});

server.send({
    text:  emailbericht,
    from:    "fromname <from-email@gmail.com>",
    to:      "toname <to-email@gmail.com>",
    subject: "Nieuw contactbericht"
}, function(err, message) { console.log(err); });
```

gmai-send:

```
      var send = require('gmail-send')({
            user: 'from-email@gmail.com',             
            pass: 'pw',            
            to:   'my-email@gmail.com',        
            subject: 'Niew contactbericht',
            text:    emailbericht            
          });


          send({}, function (err, res) {
            console.log('* [example1] send(): err:', err, '; res:', res);
          });
```

Now I don't really know what could be wrong. I couldn't find any solution that fixes this.

Maybe somebody here knows if I need to change my code or should be fixing some settings on my VPS.

edit extra:
ping:

> PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (173.194.69.109) 56(84) bytes of
>   data. 64 bytes from ef-in-f109.1e100.net (173.194.69.109): icmp_seq=1
>   ttl=46 time=4.34 ms 64 bytes from ef-in-f109.1e100.net
>   (173.194.69.109): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=4.41 ms 64 bytes from
>   ef-in-f109.1e100.net (173.194.69.109): icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=4.38 ms
>   64 bytes from ef-in-f109.1e100.net (173.194.69.109): icmp_seq=4 ttl=46
>   time=4.31 msq

Exception gmail-send (uses nodemailer):

> ```
>  [example1] send(): err: { Error: Connection timeout
>     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/ijsverenigingpeeloservernode/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:557:19)
>     at SMTPConnection._onError (/ijsverenigingpeeloservernode/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:530:20)
>     at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/ijsverenigingpeeloservernode/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:248:18)
>     at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
>     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
>     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' } ; res: undefined
> ```

Error message emailjs:

> { [Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server] code: 4, smtp:
>   undefined }

Comment: What happens if you try `ping smtp.gmail.com` from your VPS?  What is the EXACT error you get?

Comment: @jfriend00 Added extra information

Comment: @ProCx Did you find solution for this...  I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: I didn't find anything yet. Haven't implemented something for it now and I'm using a different solution